# What's the correct way to use structured data jsonLD in Next.js 13 app-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, app-router

I was trying to add structured data in my nextJS 13(app router) application but couldn't find the correct method.

Next-seo package also gives errors

I tried next-seo but got this error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

While adding 
To the layout.js in the app directory

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <NextSeo useAppDir={true} />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        {/* <GlobalContextProvider>{children}</GlobalContextProvider> */}
        <Analytics />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error you are getting kindly mentioned but as I understand hope It will help you

In Next.js 13, you can use structured data in JSON-LD format by leveraging the Head component and the built-in next-seo package. Here's an example of how you can implement structured data using JSON-LD in a Next.js 13 app with the app-router:

Install the required dependencies by running the following command in your project directory:
lua

```
npm install next-seo
```

Create a new file, for example, Layout.js, where you will define the layout component for your app. In this component, you can set up the structured data using the next-seo package.
jsx

```
import { DefaultSeo, NextSeo } from 'next-seo';
import Head from 'next/head';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <DefaultSeo
        // Define default SEO configuration here
      />
      <Head>
        {/* Add additional meta tags or stylesheets here */}
        <script
          type="application/ld+json"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: JSON.stringify({
              '@context': 'https://schema.org',
              '@type': 'Organization',
              name: 'Your Organization Name',
              url: 'https://www.example.com',
              // Add more structured data properties here
            }),
          }}
        />
      </Head>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

In your _app.js file, import and wrap your app with the Layout component.
jsx

```
import Layout from './Layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In your individual pages, you can set specific SEO and structured data using the NextSeo component from next-seo. For example:
jsx

```
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';

const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NextSeo
        title="My Page Title"
        description="Description of my page"
        // Add more SEO properties here
      />
      {/* Rest of your page content */}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

By following these steps, you can add structured data in JSON-LD format to your Next.js 13 app using the next-seo package and the Head component. This approach allows you to define default SEO configurations, set up global structured data, and override them on a per-page basis as needed.

Comment: but this is not working for app router... <Head/> tag isn't supported there

Comment: Yes. Above, you find the correct solution for App Router. If one would rather not follow the official recommendation, she or he is on his own.

Answer (score -1):

This is [the official solution](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#json-ld) for inserting schema.org JSON-LD. I tested this approach and it works.

```
export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const product = await getProduct(params.id)
 
  const jsonLd = {
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': 'Product',
    name: product.name,
    image: product.image,
    description: product.description,
  }
 
  return (
    <section>
      {/* Add JSON-LD to your page */}
      <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </section>
  )
}
```